# "fromJust" vs. "Just =" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

Haskell newbie here. I'm trying to understand [this](http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/gallery/FibCalls.html) example from Haskell's `diagrams` library. Specifically, there's a line like this:

`Just t = <thing>` where `<thing>` is of type `Maybe (Tree a)`

I don't understand what this is doing. I understand that we need to get the value out from the `Maybe`. I replaced that line of code with

`t = fromJust <thing>`

and it works the same. Is there any difference between the two lines, and can anyone explain what the first line is doing?

Comment: Side note: consider using `fmap` instead of `fromJust` or `Just t = ...`

Comment: There is a subtle difference between the two that doesn't appear in the semantics: when `...` is `Nothing`, `Just t = ...` will give you an error with a line pointing to that pattern; `t = fromJust ...` will give you an error with a line pointing to the implementation of `fromJust`.

Comment: the difference is convenience of use of `fromJust` in [tag:pointfree] chains of expressions.

Comment: As Daniel said: The pattern matching approach makes the difference between the program dying with a useless `I'm so sorry` and a helpful error message with source code location. Avoid `fromJust`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`fromJust` is pretty much equivalent to:

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust (Just t) = t
```

Note that it’s the same [pattern match](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html)! If you’re sure that your `Maybe` going to be a `Just` and not a `Nothing`, you can use `fromJust` to get its value without pattern matching, but matching is cleaner in most cases, so you don’t need it here.

Comment: Tautological note to the OP: when in doubt, assume you're *not* sure that the `Maybe` is going to be a `Just`. Also, one reason that matching is cleaner in this case is because it makes it more obvious that you are skipping a case. GHC can even warn you of that through the flag `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, which won't happen if you use `fromJust`.

Answer (score 5):

Although both forms serve the same purpose,

in case of unexpected error, the pattern matching form will give you a better clue of the error location. (*fromJust* error exception is thrown from within *fromJust*, while failed pattern matching will give you the file, line and columns of the incomplete code)

```
$ ghci
Prelude> :m +Data.Maybe

Prelude Data.Maybe> let t = fromJust Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe> t
*** Exception: Maybe.fromJust: Nothing

Prelude Data.Maybe> let Just t = Nothing
Prelude Data.Maybe> t
*** Exception: <interactive>:7:5-20: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just t
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are quite sure that the `Maybe` type is going to return a `Just` value, you can just pattern match and extract the value.

Example:

`Just t = Just 3` will assing the value 3 to `t`. You can load this in `ghci` and verify that for yourself. `fromJust` is the same, but it is more of a function application.